# how to return multiple values from User defined function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, user-defined-functions

Need help with SQL user_defined function that I created. 
My function should return the type of the item based on item number that I give. 
When I execute the function I get an error

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression."

I think I should change this functions return type to a table. However I don't know how to do it. 
Here is my function:

```
create function [dbo].[fx_calculate_type](@item varchar)
returns varchar(10)
AS 
begin
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10)
       ,@typeCount int
       ,@MaxYear int 
       ,@redoitem varchar(18)

set @type = ''
set @typeCount = (Select count(m.year) 
                  from mr m
                  where m.item_no = 'RR301') --@item  
set @MaxYear =   (Select Max(m.year) 
                  from mr m
                  where m.item_no = 'RR301') --@item  
set @redoitem =  (select redoitem 
                  from  mr m
                  where m.item_no = 'RR301') --@item   

       if (@redoitem is null or @redoitem= '')

      BEGIN 
      While (@typeCount>=1)
         Begin
         Continue 
            If @typeCount = 1
                Begin 
                set @type = 'N'
                   --return (@type )
                End
            Else 
                Begin
                set @type = @typeCount+ 'C'
                set @MaxYear =@MaxYear -1 --2014
                set @typeCount = @typeCount -1  --4
                  -- return (@type) 
                END
          END
       END 

       Else
          BEGIN 
      While (@typeCount>=1)
         Begin
         Continue 
            If @typeCount = 1
                Begin 
                set @type = 'N'
                   --return (@type)  
                End
            Else 
                Begin
                set @type = @typeCount+ 'R'
                set @MaxYear =@MaxYear -1 --2014
                set @typeCount = @typeCount -1  --4
                   --return (@type)  
                END
          END
       END
     return (@type) 
      END
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Your code seems way too complicated for the description you give.  But the third `set` with a subquery would cause the error you are describing.

Comment: Your loop looks like you need to have a table valued function, this is a scalar function, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Comment: You need a multi-statement table valued function and return a table back from the function or use a stored procedure with multiple OUTPUT parameters (preferred) . Also you function takes a parameter of `varchar` type without any length defined , anything to pass to this variable will be truncated to default length of `1`. You need to explicitly define the length for this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me! Thanks

create proc [dbo].[type]
@item varchar(10) 
AS 
begin
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10)
       ,@typeCount int
       ,@MaxYear int 
       ,@redoitem varchar(18)

set @type = ''
set @typeCount = (Select  count(DISTINCT m.year) 
                  from mr m
                  where m.item_no = @item) --@item

set @MaxYear =   (Select distinct Max(m.year) 
                  from mr m
                  where m.item_no = @item)

set @redoitem =  (select top 1 redoitem 
                  from  mr m
                  where m.item_no = @item)

IF (@redoitem is null or @redoitem= '') BEGIN
    WHILE (@typeCount>=1) BEGIN

```
    IF @typeCount = 1 
        BEGIN 
    SET @type = 'N'     
    UPDATE mr  SET type =@type WHERE item_no = @item AND year = @MaxYear    
    END
    ELSE        
        BEGIN

        set @type = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@typeCount)+ 'C'    
        UPDATE mr  SET type =@type WHERE item_no = @item AND year = @MaxYear
        SET @MaxYear =@MaxYear -1

    END

        SET @typeCount = @typeCount -1  
    CONTINUE
END
```

END

Else BEGIN 
While (@typeCount>=1) Begin

If @typeCount = 1
    Begin 
    set @type = 'N'
    UPDATE mr  SET type =@type WHERE item_no = @item AND year = @MaxYear
End
Else 
    Begin
    set @type = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@typeCount)+ 'R'
    UPDATE mr  SET type =@type WHERE item_no = @item AND year = @MaxYear
    set @MaxYear =@MaxYear -1 --2014
    set @typeCount = @typeCount -1  --4

END

```
    CONTINUE
  END
```

END
END